# Create an array with two fields from two diferent datatables

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem, here's my code from Controller:

```
public function searchResponse(Request $request){
        $query = $request->get('term','');
        $countries=\DB::table('countries');
        if($request->type=='countryname'){
            $countries->where('name','LIKE','%'.$query.'%');
        }
        if($request->type=='country_code'){
            $countries->where('sortname','LIKE','%'.$query.'%');
        }
           $countries=$countries->get();        
        $data=array();
        foreach ($countries as $country) {
                $data[]=array('name'=>$country->name,'sortname'=>$country->sortname);
        }
        if(count($data))
             return $data;
        else
            return ['name'=>'','sortname'=>''];
    }
```

This code creates an array to be used later but I need to create an array which will list all countries names and on second column their codes but in my situation the county_codes are not in same table with country names (so i have a 1. table with columns - Id  and name, and a second table with id name country_id (subcategory table) and they are connected by relation. How to use this code above to deal with that?
My Country Model:

```
class Country extends Model {

  public function countries()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Sortname::class);
  }
```

My Sortname (country_code) Model:

```
protected $fillable = [
      'country_id', 'title'
  ];

  public function country()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
  }
```

So on subcategory table there's column country_id which is connected as a relation to a name of a country code. Thank you for help! :)

Comment: Your $countries collection is from Country Model but then you are trying to use $country->sortname relationship (which is from Sortname Model) in your foreach.
Try using $country->countries->toArray() instead (you might want to rename it to 'sortnames' by the way). toArray() is also optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use join like this

`$countries=\DB::table('countries')->join('country_code','country_code.country_id','countries.id')->select('countries.name','country_code.sortname');`

in the section where u write

`$countries=\DB::table('countries');`

and from this you also doesn't need to write foreach loop to make array

Comment: But country_code is in different table, `$countries=\DB::table('countries'), $country_code=\DB::table('country_code')`

Comment: that is when you need a join relationship to get data from two different table. And from your description you have country_id in country_code table which serve as relation between two table

for more you can check laravel [join](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#joins)